# Setting all values in a byte array positiv

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I am having a problem right now, I am writing a programm in Java, which gives me a byte array with positive and negative values. I have to invert the negative values and make them positive, and keep the positive values positive. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: Please don't try to describe your code.  Instead, [edit] your question to include the code in question, so we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: I am writing a programm, that inputs audio data into a array, I  need a average value of 10 numbers added in the array, for the average I don't want to use negative values.

Comment: Write a for loop which assigns `Math.abs(array[k])` to each kth element of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it all works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to iterate over the byte array and find the absolute value of each element. Math.abs() should work for that. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-math-abs-method-examples/